# Refresh Power BI Data Flow using API through Azure Data Factory

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory

I am trying to refresh a PBI Data Flow using an ADF web activity by authenticating using the data factory's Managed Identity.

Here is my input to the activity:

```
{
    "url": "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/1dec5b21-ba60-409b-80cb-de61272ee504/dataflows/0e256da2-8823-498c-b779-3e7a7568137f/refreshes",
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "My-AzureVM-IR",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "AzureDataFactoryV2",
        "Host": "api.powerbi.com",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    },
    "body": "{\"notifyOption\":\"MailOnFailure\"}",
    "disableCertValidation": true,
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
    }
}
```

It generates the following error when doing a debug run:

```
Failure type: User configuration issue
Details: {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Unexpected dataflow error: "}}
```

I have tried this exact URL in Postman using Bearer Token Authentication and it works.  Our AAD Admin group said they added our ADF's Managed Identity to the permission list for the PBI API, so I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I have run into that before. Service principals (like a MSI) aren’t supported for dataflows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#considerations-and-limitations “dataflows management is not supported”. So you will have to create a regular AAD cloud only use without MFA and change the authentication. If this is acceptable let me know and I may be able to help with the pipeline

Comment: I assume I can create an AAD App registration to authenticate using a regular Service Principal instead?  Or are you saying I'm going to have to make an initial API call to get  an OAuth token first?

Comment: you need a user I believe. Not a service principal/app registration. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Going back through pipelines I have used, I do have a pipeline just like yours which uses MSI auth. So I would recommend you have done steps 2-4 in this article and try again with the MSI. If that doesn't work, let us know: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-2---create-an-azure-ad-security-group

Comment: Also, try against the Azure IR (not against a self-hosted IR). There was a bug in IR software about a year ago when MSI auth wasn't working for web activities. I don't believe you should need the self-hosted IR in this situation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an FYI, I was able to get the ADF Managed Identity working with data flow refreshes using the HTTP request in my original post.

The key was after having the Tenant Admins add the Managed Identity to a security group with API access, I then also had to add the Managed Identity to the PBI Workspace access list as a Member.

Then my API call worked from ADF using the MSI.  No Bearer login token needed.